# How do I add Inbound Rules to Windows Defender Firewall from Python?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, windows-firewall

I wrote a Python client/server which I was able to test successfully between two devices on the same network; however, the client fails to connect to the server through the public IP. My hunch is that it's a port forwarding issue in that case. I don't want my users to have to manually port forward to use my program. Is there a pythonic way to add inbound rules to Windows Defender Firewall? Alternatively, is there some other simple example of a client/server in Python that works when connecting via public IP address?

Comment: port forwarding and windows firewall rules are typically two different things, and it may be you need to configure both of these to successfully make connections. Port forwarding is typically applied at your router to your ISP.

Comment: Is there a pythonic way to port forward? Or do people have to do this manually in their routers? This feels like a common enough task that there would be a way to perform it in Python...